# React Card Carousel with no autoplay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-controls, pure-react-carousel

I've been working with React Card Carousel. I've done a page with a card carousel, but I cannot figure out how to not autoplay the cards and find a way for the user to change them.

This is the code.

```
const candidates = [
    {img: Verde, semestre: 'Formula presi/vice', names: 'P1 y P2', description: 'Hola somos ...'},
    {img: Verde, semestre: 'Primer Semestre', names: 'S1', description: 'Hola soy ...'},
    {img: Verde, semestre: 'Segundo Semestre', names: 'S2', description: 'Hola soy ...'},
    {img: Verde, semestre: 'Tercer Semestre', names: 'S3', description: 'Hola soy ...'},
    {img: Verde, semestre: 'Cuarto Semestre', names: 'S4', description: 'Hola soy ...'},
    {img: Verde, semestre: 'Quinto Semestre', names: 'S5', description: 'Hola soy ...'},
    {img: Verde, semestre: 'Sexto Semestre', names: 'S6', description: 'Hola soy ...'},
    {img: Verde, semestre: 'Septimo Semestre', names: 'S7', description: 'Hola soy ...'},
    {img: Verde, semestre: 'Octavo Semestre', names: 'S8', description: 'Hola soy ...'}
];

const ImageSlider = () => {
    return(
        <>
            <NavB />
            <ReactCardCarousel autoplay={true} autoplay_speed={4500}>
                 {candidates.map((slide, index)=>{
                    return(
                    <div>
                        <Candidate data={slide} />
                    </div>)
                })}
            </ReactCardCarousel>
    
        </>
    )
}
```

Where the Candidate component is the next one:

```
import {
  MDBCard,
  MDBCardTitle,
  MDBCardText,
  MDBCardBody,
  MDBCardImage,
  MDBRow,
  MDBCol
} from 'mdb-react-ui-kit';

const Candidate = ({data}) => {
    return (
        <MDBCard style={{width: '500px', height:'300px'}}>
            <MDBRow className='g-0'>
                <MDBCol md='4'>
                <MDBCardImage src={data.img} alt='...' fluid />
                </MDBCol>
                <MDBCol md='8'>
                <MDBCardBody>
                    <MDBCardTitle>{data.names} {data.semestre}</MDBCardTitle>
                    <MDBCardText>
                    {data.description}
                    </MDBCardText>
                </MDBCardBody>
                </MDBCol>
            </MDBRow>
        </MDBCard>
    );
}
```

I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks in advice :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have a boolean state(set to false) in the Carousel page and provide a toggle for letting the user change the value.

Currently, you ae setting autoplay to true by default, instead of which pass the newly defined state.

Comment: Thanks, The state would change after the user make a click, right?

Comment: Yes. By default set some value and whenever the user clicks the toggle, change the state value from true to false or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

there is props in package that you use content `autoplay` and `autoplay_speed` take a look [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-card-carousel#props) for more details

Comment: I have tried to change those values, but It has not been effective, I do not want an autoplay, I want the user to change the card.